# Getting focus on an edit text when pressing other view

Tags: android, view

i have a button and an edit text.
I want to press the button and want the action to happen on edit text same that happens when edit text is pressed itself i.e. a keyboard opens for writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this on button click,

InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                mgr.showSoftInput(edit_text, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
                edit_text.requestFocus();